# How To Create models Connect ODBC mySQL with Visual Studio

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, connection, odbc, visual-studio-2019

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Collections;
using System.Linq;
using System.Web;
using System.Web.Mvc;
using System.Data.Odbc;
using System.Data.SqlClient;


namespace BroNetNew.Models
{
    public class DataConn
    {
        string MyConString = "Driver={MySQL ODBC 5.3 Unicode Driver};" +
                  "SERVER=localhost;" +
                  "DATABASE=Bee;" +
                  "UID=root;" +
                  "PASSWORD=123;" +
                  "OPTION=4";

        OdbcConnection MyConnection = new OdbcConnection(myConString);
        MyConnection.Open();
        string sql = "SELECT * from member";
        OdbcConnection conn = null;
        OdbcCommand comm = null;
        OdbcDataReader dr = null;
        conn = new OdbcConnection(MyConString);
        conn.Open();
        comm = new OdbcCommand(sql, conn);
        dr = comm.ExecuteReader();
    }
}
```

I don't know how to make it work and how to get data from table member(MY DB name:Bee in MyConString)

Please Help ... I First time use asp.net MVC.

Thank You...

Comment: First of all **RED FLAG** *never share your credentials online* remove the server `IP address` and `username` and `password`, use a dummy if you have to and the image is just a duplicate of the code. So, no need for that. And as for your query, you have two connections `MyConnection` and `conn` no need, use only one.  As for why you are receiving the data. You have initiated an [ExecuteReader](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.data.oledb.oledbcommand.executereader?view=netframework-4.8) but haven't made any code to read the data coming from the query.

Comment: @vikscool thx u

Comment: flow the steps https://dev.mysql.com/doc/visual-studio/en/visual-studio-making-a-connection.html

Comment: It appears that you have posted sensitive/private information. Please reset your passwords and/or revoke API keys and tokens, as they are considered compromised when posted on the internet. If personally-identifiable information was posted, please [edit] out the info then flag your post for a moderator to redact the prior revisions.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
 public class DataConn
    {
        string MyConString = "Driver={MySQL ODBC 5.3 Unicode Driver};" +
                  "SERVER=localhost;" +
                  "DATABASE=Bee;" +
                  "UID=root;" +
                  "PASSWORD=123;" +
                  "OPTION=4"; //  ODBC connection
        string Query = "SELECT * from member"; // Write Query

        using (OdbcConnection c = new OdbcConnection(myConString)) //New Connection
        {
            OdbcCommand cmd = new OdbcCommand(Query, c); 
            c.Open(); // Connection Open

            OdbcDataReader dr = cmd.ExecuteReader();
            // dr will get all data u want
            // Query better use "SELECT column[0], column[1] FROM `member`";
            // dr.GetString(0); -> for column[0]
            // dr.GetString(1); -> for column[1]
            // do something...
        }
    }
```